# std::vector abort problem

Tags: c++, vector, stdvector, abort

I'm having diffuculty with the example below, the last line is producing an "abort has been called" error. I don't see why this should be.

I'm using (*abc).def instead of abc->def for clarity in this case.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class branch
{
    public:
        unsigned short n;
        std::vector<branch> branches;

        branch left()
        {
            return branches.at(0);
        }
};

void main()
{
    branch trunk = branch();
        trunk.n = 0;
        branch b1, b2;
        b1.n = 0;
        b2.n = 5;
        b1.branches.push_back(b2);
        trunk.branches.push_back(b1);

    branch* focus1 = &(trunk.branches.at(0));
    branch* focus3 = &(trunk.left());

    std::cout<<trunk.left().branches.at(0).n<<std::endl; // ok
    std::cout<<(*focus1).branches.at(0).n<<std::endl; // ok
    std::cout<<(*focus1).left().n<<std::endl; // ok
    std::cout<<(*focus3).branches.at(0).n<<std::endl; // problem
}
```

Comment: What OS? What compiler? Also -> is much more clear than (*p).def

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem with this code is that `trunk.left()` returns a copy of the branch, not a reference to the branch.  Consequently, your `focus3` pointer is pointing at a temporary object that's immediately going to be cleaned up after that line of code finishes executing.  Consequently, when you try dereferencing `focus3` on the last line, you're following a pointer to garbage data, which causes the crash.

To fix this, either have `left` return a reference to the branch, or make `focus3` a const reference, which extends the lifetime of the temporary to the lifetime of the reference.

Comment: Ah, `const` reference is good, but OP must make `const` methods to use that.

Comment: True, but I'm a firm believer that this is a good idea.  (Please don't start a flame-war with me if you disagree; it's not worth the argument.) :-)

Comment: I used a referance by adding an & after branch and before left(). This worked perfectly. In this case this solution is also a lot more efficent and permits editing as well as reading. Although this example is a simplified version of a verry different looking piece of code.